# How to order by one column and make elements with same 2nd column contino uous?

Tags: mysql

I have two columns `id` and `resolvedId`. Now i want to order the columns by `id desc` but want the columns with same `resolvedId` to appear one after other.
So far tried group by but my understanding is it can only be used for aggregate functions like sum etc. Any easy way to do this in mysql?
My other option would be to get them in php as seperate resultsets and then insert based on resolvedId.
id is unique auto_increment and resolvedId is going to be one of ids.
Sample data

```
id| name| resolvedId
1   nam    1
2   bam    4
3   sam    3
4   dam    4
5   ham    3
6   ram    4
```

Output wanted

```
id|  name|  resolvedId
6    ram    4
4    dam    4
2    bam    4
5    ham    3
3    sam    3
1    nam    1
```

Sample data 2

```
id| name| resolvedId
1   nam    1
2   bam    4
3   sam    3
4   dam    4
5   ham    3
6   ram    1
```

Output wanted

```
id|  name|  resolvedId
6    ram    1
1    nam    1
5    ham    3
3    sam    3
4    dam    4
2    bam    4
```

Comment: maybe some sample data and wished result would be better to understand , and your trying query.

Comment: ok, i'll put an example together. should take some time though.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT ..... ORDER BY id desc, resolvedID` ?

Comment: You provided some sample data, but what result do you expect? If you want to have all rows with `resolvedId = 1`, followed by all rows with `resolvedId = 3`, etc., then you need `ORDER BY resolvedID, id`.

Comment: added sample output. I want id to be sorted desc but then whenever we find a row with same resolvedId we bump it up just below the row having same resolvedId

Comment: In that case, you need `ORDER BY resolvedId, id DESC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a probably adequate solution:

```
select tbl.* from
    ( select MAX(id) as m, resolvedId from tbl GROUP BY resolvedId) as driver
    JOIN tbl 
    ON driver.resolvedId = tbl.resolvedId 
    ORDER BY driver.m desc, tbl.id desc, driver.resolvedId;
```

Works with you latest examples http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3a2f/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fb2ce/4

Comment: you got it spot on. This is a very basic example.

Comment: changed the example, and this would fail.

Comment: @NaveenSharma I edited my answer to provide an other solution that match better with your description of the problem.

Comment: hey, that still gives id 5 first, i need 6 to come first.

Comment: @NaveenSharma No, it doesn't: if you look carefully the SQLFiddle, you will see I left the two solutions in order to compare them. The "good" one is the second (you probably have to scroll the window...)

Comment: looks beautiful Sylvain. Let me try some more scenarios. thanks!

Comment: hey, i think you should remove the first solution, will be misleading. the second one works really well.

Comment: @NaveenSharma Since you confirmed that the second solution was the "good one" I removed the first answer. Updated sqlfiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, what you are asking could not be obtained without further constraints on the data set. Suppose you have the following data:

```
id    resolvedId
1              4
2              3
3              4
```

Order it by `id desc` would only result in discontinued `resolvedId`.